# Small package SPI Flash IC as logger?

Tags: spi, flash

In a project where we use STM32 as a microcontroller, we need to record 512Mbit data. As far as I know, NAND flash ICs are used extensively in flash memories(From ISSI,Panasonic,Samsung,Toshiba.. companies). But they are very big and needs lots of pins.
[image: ehttp://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/IS34-35ML01G081.pdf]
  Instead this, we want to use a spi flash which is much smaller and requires 8pins.(from Winbond, macronic, micron ..) For example;
[image: http://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25n01gv%20revl%20050918%20unsecured.pdf]
Since the device will operate with battery, it is also important to have **low power**.
Can we use spi flash in this project? Is there a handicap to use?

Comment: The SPI flash will come with a data sheet that defines power usage, and how to talk to it, as well as limitations. To me, it's not clear what your actual question is that wouldn't be answered by "read the datasheet".

Comment: *Is there a handicap...?*  They are slower, which normally isn't an issue for a data logger. But, you didn't give us enough information to help with that.

Comment: NAND flash IC is used in all the flash memory I have seen, why cheaper and smaller SPI flash is not used, that's why I'm surprised.I was wondering if there was actually something I missed or didn't know.

Comment: If I give more details, it will be a device that can record data from the microphone  as well as logging some events. I think that's enough for 48kHz?

Comment: SPI NOR flashes aren't sold in the capacity you request.  You'll need at least 2, more likely 4 parts in an array.  At that point you may find that the NAND parts, especially in a BGA package, aren't that much bigger.

Comment: Chris, Is there sth. i don't know. For example, this is 512Mbit SPI Flash.https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/micron-technology-inc/MT25QL512ABB1EW9-0SIT/557-1786-ND/6622722

Comment: Why no microSD card?

Answer (score 5):

> Can we use spi flash in this project? Is there a handicap to use?

No reason why it wouldn't work. Make sure your micro has a SPI port, that you map the pins and configure it correctly...

Regarding power, make sure to compare idle current values from various datasheets.

DO NOT cut the power to the Flash while it is writing, or when you think it's finished but has not really finished. This will corrupt data. Use the deep-power-down command instead.

There is probably an optimum data chunk size to write regarding power. I mean, the flash will take some time to wake up so it probably doesn't make sense to wake it up to write one byte and then go back to sleep. You'll have to buffer data in RAM and then write it when enough is available. Why not measure total energy use per written byte with several chunk sizes?

Also, SPI flashes tend to be slow at writing, so make sure the throughput is adequate.

> NAND flash IC is used in all the flash memory I have seen, why cheaper and smaller SPI flash is not used

The big chips have address pins, which makes random reads quite fast. On a SPI flash, you have to input each address bit serially, making random reads extremely slow. On burst reads, where you input the address once and read a significant amount of data, SPI flash is okay. They are often used to store firmware which is read once at boot and then transferred into SRAM, in this case random access speed does not matter. But if you want to run code directly from a flash, then it matters, and a big chip with address pins will be much faster. Some micros are able to execute code from quad SPI flash, they use a small SRAM as cache, it can be useful but there is still a speed penalty.

**Also consider using a MicroSD card:** if you write to it with the usual FAT32 filesystem, then it can be read directly by a computer, and you don't have to program all the code for reading and transferring the data from your datalogger into a PC. Just use a card reader.

Comment: The obvious reason it won't work is that SPI (NOR) flash parts with the asker's required capacity aren't sold.  They'd have to do an array of multiple chips.

Comment: I see 512Mbit NOR SPI flash chips [in stock at mouser](https://www.mouser.fr/Semiconductors/Memory-ICs/NOR-Flash/_/N-488w1?P=1z0w0i3Z1z0y176&Ns=Pricing|0). Personally I'd use a microSD card though.

Comment: Peufeu, this is actually my question. Even the smallest sd card is larger than spi flash.

Comment: How about the size of the battery?